# Why does .MSI file open read-only?

Tags: installation, windows-installer, acl, orca

I am attempting to open a **.MSI installer package file** to modify it. Whenever I try to open it, it opens in **read-only mode**. I see this with [Orca](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370557%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), with [InstEd](http://www.instedit.com/), or when opening the file directly via code:

```
 `MsiOpenDatabase()` (ERROR_OPEN_FAILED with MSIDBOPEN_DIRECT or 
                      MSIDBOPEN_TRANSACT persistence modes).
```

- The file itself does *not* have the read-only attribute set (in fact, has *no* attributes set)
- I am using an account with Administrators group access
- As far as I can tell, no other process has the file open
- No installs are in progress or suspended
- I can copy the file to another location, and open it read/write there. But the original, I cannot touch

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Are you running Orca as admin?

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that this is caused by one of the following factors:

- **Custom NTFS access rights** - defined for the file in its security descriptor
- **The file might be "blocked"** - marked with a special flag after being downloaded via **Internet Explorer**.

The resolution for the latter is to right click the file and select properties and click the **unblock button** at the bottom of the property page and pressing OK.

The resolution for custom NTFS rights are done in a similar way by going into the security
tab of the property page for the file, but it is easier just to copy and paste the file and use the fresh copy with the default security.

Answer (score 1):

Found it.

@Glytzhkof, you almost had it but there's a detail I did not know about, and left out. This is a package that lies in a folder under "access protection" by my system's anti-virus program: a filesystem hook that blocks modification of critical system and AV files. Turn off access protection temporarily, and the file is wide open.

Fortunately, one of my teammates had some experience with this, and suggested I try it. Bingo.

Thanks, all.

Comment: I bet it might block vbscript custom actions also! :)

Answer (score 0):

What I have done to get it working was to create first a backup of the MSI file, and then open that backup. It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Try to close/kill processes that might interfere, for example:

- Other running Install shield instances
- Installshield updater
- Installshield licensing service
- Antivirus